# enable and disable datawedge profile

Tags: android, datawedge, zebra

In my device i have two APPs which used use scan barcodes for different purpose & they both have two different profiles Ex. "Profile 1" & "Profile 2"  the only different between two is `Intent delivery: Send via startActivity` for "Profile 1" and for "Profile -2" the `intenet delivery:Boradcast intent` what happen if i am running `profile-1` then `profile-2` both the app can scan but when first running `profile-1` then `profile-2` the `profile-1` app cant scan , so i want to `disable` the profile when app is not in use and `enable` it when app is use . in that case it work seamlessly

Comment: How do you switch between profiles in your apps? Did you [associate the profiles](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/11-3/guide/createprofile/#associatetheprofilewithappsandoractivities) with your apps/activities? You can use [GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/latest/guide/api/getactiveprofile/) API to get the current profile or [SWITCH_TO_PROFILE](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/latest/guide/api/switchtoprofile/) API to change the current profile.

Comment: If you really need to disable a profile you can use [SET_CONFIG](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/latest/guide/api/setconfig/) API and its `PROFILE_ENABLED` bundle parameter to enable/disable the profile. I don't believe this is the right way, because you will have to enable profiles yourself at the right time. The best approach is to have properly configured profiles and let the DataWedge do all the work.